# String Kernels in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining

I have been using the stringdot function available in R in "Kernlab" package.Here is my code

```
library(kernlab)
x <- c("1","2","3")
y <- c("3","2","1")
lst <- list(x, y)
sk <- stringdot(length = 2, lambda = 1.2, type = "exponential", normalized = TRUE)
q <- kernelMatrix(sk,lst)
```

As per my knowledge, the exponential kernel will create substrings of length 2. For example, here the strings will be `1-2,1-3,2-3` from the first vector and `3-2,3-1,2-1` from the second vector. It will try to match the input by creating various substrings of the given length and reducing the weight of the substrings as per the given value of `lambda`.

As per my expectations, the output should contain a value of 1 for (x,x) and (y,y) and a value 0 for (x,y),
as there are no common substrings between the given inputs, but the output is showing the value of (x,y) pair to be 0.4723.

I don't understand why the similarity between x and y is 0.4723.

Comment: Regarding exponential string kernel,I am familiar with the working of the exponential string kernel suggested by "H Lodhi" in "Text classification using string kernels".I was unable to find the reference to the kernel used in kernlab package and the result of the Lodhi's and this kernlab doesn't match.Do specify the main differences between this and the String Subsequence kernel from Lodhi's.

Comment: Shouldn't a string kernel compare n-grams instead of all possible pairs ?

Comment: @Drey Exactly ,I was not aware of the term n-gram.I think the strings that I have given above of length 2 are acting like bi-grams ,aren't they?

Comment: almost - they would be 1-2, 2-3 but not 1-3 for x. And 3-2, 2-1 for y.

Comment: You mean gaps are not allowed between sub-sequences,but then it should certainly be zero as when I replace the exponential with other kernels like spectrum available in the same package ,which doesn't allow gaps, I am getting zero similarity between (x,y).

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the source of `kernelMatrix` and `stringdot`, it's possible to work out what's happening with your input.

When a list is passed as `x` to `kernelMatrix`, it does the following:

```
if (is(x, "list")) 
  x <- sapply(x, paste, collapse = "")
```

In your case, this means that your `lst` input becomes `c("123", "321")`.

`kernelMatrix` then takes this vector, and generates a matrix with the following pattern (where `sk` is the stringkernel function):

```
sk("123", "123")    sk("123", "321")
                    sk("321", "321")
```

The lower left cell is then filled in with the upper right, and the whole matrix is normalised by dividing by the square-root of the upper-left cell multiplied by the lower right.

You can check the individual value matches by doing this:

```
stringdot(type = "exponential", lambda = 1.2)(123, 321)
#[1] 0.4723893
```

It's worth noting that the `length` parameter does nothing for `type = "exponential"`. Each type of `stringkernel` only has zero or one parameters, and for `exponential` it's `lambda` which gives the decay. The substring weight decays as the matching substring gets shorter, with `lambda` as the decay factor.

`stringdot(type = "spectrum")`, as described in the manual, uses `length` and will only match subsequences of at least that length. Since there is no matching substring >= 2 characters between `123` and `321`, the comparison comes out as zero.

It should also be noted that a newline character (`"\n"`) is appended to each string, and that even single character matches will have a result >0 using `type = "exponential"`, so it's not possible to get a result of zero. e.g.

```
stringdot(type = "exponential", lambda = 1.2)("blowfish", "mage")
#[1] 0.05274495
```

Finally, it looks as though @Rahul wanted an implementation in R of [Lodhi's 2002 algorithm](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume2/lodhi02a/lodhi02a.pdf). `kernlab` does not implement this algorithm, and I'm not aware of an R package that does. There seems to be a python implementation available at [github](https://github.com/timshenkao/StringKernelSVM), but I've not checked whether the code runs let alone gives the output requested. It would be possible for someone with an interest to reimplement the python code in R if that were felt useful/necessary.

### Additional edit to address comment:

Results of normalised stringkernel functions depend on the degree to which each string is similar to itself.

```
sk_u <- stringdot(type = "exponential", lambda = 1.2, normalized = FALSE)
sk_n <- stringdot(type = "exponential", lambda = 1.2, normalized = TRUE)

lapply(list(unnormalised = sk_u, normalised = sk_n), function(f) {
  c(
    "ab,xyzabqr" = f("ab", "xyzabqr"),
    "ab,abpmnop" = f("ab", "abpmnop"),
    "ab,ab" = f("ab"),
    "xyzabqr,xyzabqr" = f("xyzabqr"),
    "abpmnop,abpmnop" = f("abpmnop")
  )
})

#$unnormalised
#     ab,xyzabqr      ab,abpmnop           ab,ab xyzabqr,xyzabqr abpmnop,abpmnop 
#       3.194444        3.194444        4.467593       20.814201       22.480868 

#$normalised
#     ab,xyzabqr      ab,abpmnop           ab,ab xyzabqr,xyzabqr abpmnop,abpmnop 
#      0.3312674       0.3187513       1.0000000       1.0000000       1.0000000
```

It can be seen that unnormalised, the result is the same for either comparison. However, since the normalised result is equal to (e.g.) `sk_u("ab", "xyzabqr") / sqrt(sk_u("ab") * sk_u("xyzabqr"))`, the reason that `sk_n("ab", "xyzabqr")` scores higher relates to the fact that there are two p's in `"abpmnop"`.

Comment: Amazing backtracking.But I am looking for the proper algorithm used in the exponential kernel. Regarding the value 0.4723,why are we getting this value as there is no common sub-string or sub-sequence between the two?Also if we replace let's say `y=c("4","5","6")` even then we are getting a value of 0.1180 between x and y.

Comment: @Rahul `kernlab` doesn't implement the Lodhi method. See my edits above.

Comment: Thank you Nick for your time.I was aware of the fact that 'kernlab' doesn't implement Lodhi's method,its clear from the value of lambda in Lodhi's method its value should be between [0,1] but here in kernlab it should be greater than one.I am not looking for Lodhi's method but the algorithm or at least reference to the source from where it was taken as the result is not clear even after taking into account the '\n', lets say we are comparing x1="ab" to two strings x2="xyzabqr" and x3="abpmnop" shouldn't the value of (x1,x3) be greater than (x1,x2) ? In result it's opposite.

Comment: @Rahul see edit above. In brief, it's because of the two p's in `"abpmnop"`

Comment: The point that I was trying to make by the above example is that even if you take something that have all the characters different say something like x1="ab", x2="aqwerb" ,x3="abmnop" the decay factor is not coming into the picture, for both (x1,x2) in which there is a lot of gap between the characters "a" and "b",and (x1,x3) in which the characters "a" ,"b" are together the values are same.

Comment: As per the help, the decay factor means that shorter substring matches are worth less per character matched than longer ones. So matching a four character substring is worth more than double a two character one. None of the `kernlab` string kernels handle noncontiguous matches. The reason your two examples score the same is because in both cases there is a two character match (`b\n` for x1,x2 and `ab` for x1,x3) and a one character match ('a' and '\n' respectively). Try `aqwebr` and you'll find the result is lower because you then just have three single character matches (`a`, `b`, `\n`)